# Image/hover/text is not centered

Tags: css

On my page, i have rows of images, with a hover attribute that reveals text. However, the images are not centered. This seems to be a div problem that is possibly clashing with my mainframe div, although i am not sure.

Can anyone spot the problem?

**CSS**

```
#mainframe {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 80%;
}

#mainwrapper {  
    font: 10pt normal Arial, sans-serif;  
    text-align: center;  
}  

#mainwrapper .box {
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#mainwrapper .box img {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}

#mainwrapper .box .caption {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}

#mainwrapper .box .fade-caption, #mainwrapper .box .scale-caption {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: middle;
    padding: 0px;
}

#mainwrapper .box:hover .fade-caption {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: post the related code here rather than the link... the link may not work in near future..which in turn won't help any user looking for an answer

Comment: Your URL gives me a 404 page from you hosting provider.

Comment: have you tried `margin: 0px auto`?

Comment: Sorry guys, i'm new to this site, relevant code has been added. Satpal - I've added that code in, but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `#mainwrapper` remove `text-align: center;` so that the entire div stand in center.

Also change the below css `text-align: middle;` is wrong should be `center`

```
#mainwrapper .box .fade-caption, #mainwrapper .box .scale-caption {
opacity: 0;
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
margin: 0px auto;
text-align: middle;  // change it center
padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: @user2567471 I'm glad that I was able to help.